# convert base64 to sound file in php tone sound is rustle

Tags: php, audio, base64

I Convert Base64 string in php to mp3 sound file but produced file wav Corrupted

Before convert tone sound is rustle

Such as voice files that convert :

http://vocaroo.com/i/s1Dlol5Wu3Zo

php code :

```
<?php 



if(isset($_POST['audio'])){

$data = str_replace('data:audio/wav;base64,', '', $_POST['audio']); 

 $data = base64_decode($data);

$track_name =   get_random_string(mt_rand(6,10)) . ".mp3";

$upl_dir    =    "../up/" . $track_name;

if( !file_put_contents($upl_dir, $data) ){

    $response['status']     =   1;

    $response['message']    =   "File could not be uploaded. Try again >later.";

echo $data;

echo "E1";

}

echo $data;

}
```

I test sound before convert And was right.

Base64 Code :

https://ufile.io/174101

js code base64 creator:

```
function base641()
    {

         Fr.voice.export(function(url){
    // console.log("Here is the base64 URL : " + url);
       base = url;
       ejem2 = 1;
     // alert("Check the web console for the URL");
     // $("<a href='"+ url +"' target='_blank'></a>")[0].click();

    }, "base64");

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
file_put_contents('audio.mp3', base64_decode($data));
```

Comment: Can you share that ? I want to try in my local. Its pretty tough to get the exact one. But its possible.

Comment: https://encodable.com/cgi-bin/filechucker.cgi?action=landing&path=/dd/base64/&file=base64.txt

Comment: Trying . Downloaded from the first one. in the question also you edit and give it. Others can also think then

Comment: No luck. Some issue with the base 64. Could you please try with any others and give it a try

Comment: I added js function base64 in question